# How to Implement Collision Detection

Tags: c++, simulation

I'm creating a program which simulates a robot moving around a map. I have an environment class which holds the robot and obstacles the robot could run into. At the moment I have class objects for my robot, and obstacles and I have a function which tells me if they collide (returns true/false). I am just not sure how to put it into the movement function for the robot.

The robot is a square and has a center point (x,y) a width, length and some orientation in degrees (fyi, the environment class is a friend of the robot class). The obstacles are circles with a center point (x,y) and a radius.

```
  class Environment{
  Robot robot;
  vector<Obstacle> obstacles;

  //random obstacle generation function

  bool collision_circle(Obstacle obstacle) {
      //Check if the circle intersects any of the corners of the robot
      std::vector<Point> points;
      points.push_back(robot.top_right);
      points.push_back(robot.top_left);
      points.push_back(robot.bottom_right);
      points.push_back(robot.bottom_left);

      Point obst_center(obstacle.return_x(), obstacle.return_y());

      for (int i = 0; i < points.size(); i++) {
        points[i].set_distance(obst_center);
        if (points[i].distance <= obstacle.return_radius()) { return  true; }
      }

      //Sort the points by distance away from the obstacle
      std::sort(points.begin(), points.end(), less_than());

      //Use the two closest to the obstacle to create a line
      double m = (points[0].x - points[1].x) / (points[0].y - 
      points[1].y);
      double b = points[0].y - (m * points[0].x);

      //Determine a line perpendicular which intersects the obstacle's 
      center
      double m_perp = 1 / m;
      double b_perp = obst_center.y - (m * obst_center.x);

      Point on Robot closest to obstacle
      double new_x = (b - b_perp) / (m_perp - m);
      double new_y = m_perp * new_x + b_perp;

      distance between points
      double diff_x = obst_center.x - new_x;
      double diff_y = obst_center.y - new_y;
      double distance = sqrt(pow(diff_x, 2) + pow(diff_y, 2));

      if (distance <= obstacle.return_radius()) { return true; }
      else { return false; }
  }

  Environment(Robot& t_robot): robot(t_robot) {}

  void forward(double num_inches){
    robot.y += num_inches * sin(robot.orientation * convert_deg); 
    //Convert_deg is a global variable = PI/180
    robot.x += num_inches * cos(robot.orientation * convert_deg);
  }
  //void backward, left, right, etc.
}
```

I tried having the forward function check for intersection with each obstacle (up to 15 on the map) after a certain increment of distance, but that froze up my program or would have required thousands of calculations for each inch covered. Am I even on the right track in how to execute this? I am also using SFML for graphics, but, from what I know, it only supports bounding box collision detection. Also, I want the graphics to be something secondary to the program. I am writing this so that I can create and test an program for the robot's movement and would eventually like to just run the sample and be told if it worked and watch the replay if I want.

Comment: Honestly, the above code does not look "slow".  One thing to consider is to work with the square of the distance - this prevents the square root call, but on a modern CPU, this is not too bad. If the program is locking up, I would look for infinite loops in the code (bugs), and not for faster math.

Comment: You can use [bounding boxes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Games/Techniques/3D_collision_detection) to compute *possible* contact and then use more sophisticated math, like circle contact, to compute actual contact.

Comment: @MichaelDorgan, I was stuck in an infinite loop. Thank you. After some debugging with that in mind, I found a stupid (on my part) error. I am still curious if there are better ways to implement this kind of function

Comment: @arc-menace This may be off-topic (hence a comment), but considering that you know the position of your robot and the position of the obstacles, if your goal is to move the robot from one position to another, there are many graph-based approaches to perform such task. If you have only local information - for example, data around the robot gathered by a sensor or anything like that that you wish to simulate - then you can use DWA, Potential Fields and other techniques.

Comment: The approach I would take depends strongly upon the number of obstacles that you expect to avoid.  For cases like above, storing a bounding radius (squared) for the box and doing a very quick my radius^2 + obstacle radius ^2  < distance^2 between us check.  Then its just an add of the stored squared radius values compared to the cartesian differences squared (x1-x0)^2+(y1-y0)^2  with no square root.  All together: 1 add, 2 subtracts, 2 multiplies, and a compare.  Combine that with your "inside the square" check above and rarely will you need to sort anything.